# Xamarin Forms: MediaElement: How to stick the control bar always on top of the screen?

Tags: xamarin.forms, mediaelement

I am using `MediaElement` for playing audio. My problem is the controls(Play, pause, and duration bar) are not showing always. If I tap on the `MediaElement` the controls are showing else only a black screen. I need to keep the controls always there at the whole time of audio play.

**Currently audios are playing like below:**

[image]

I tried true value for `KeepScreenOn` and `ShowsPlaybackControls` properties, but no luck.

**I need output like below screenshot:**

[image]

I can't use webview here because I need to perform some operations when the audio play end.

Comment: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/13094

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**MediaElement** is still in preview . In your case you could implement the VideoPlayer by using Custom Renderer .Check  [create the platform video players](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/video-player/player-creation) .

In addition , you could also use the plugin **[MediaPlayer](https://github.com/Baseflow/XamarinMediaManager)** from nuget .

If you do want to implement it by using MediaElement . You could post the feature request to [github](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues) and we will follow up it .